# LiteDB - Need access to LiteDB Studio; not able to build Git solution

Tags: litedb

Can someone please show me where I can get a Zip of the latest compiled build for LiteDB Studio?

I'm asking because I'm unable to build the Git solution.

I used Git to download over both the LiteDB and LiteDB.Studio projects, attempted to build the solution and got the following errors:

Error       Couldn't process file Forms\MainForm.resx due to its being in the Internet or Restricted zone or having the mark of the web on the file. Remove the mark of the web if you want to process these files. LiteDB.Studio

Error   MSB3644 The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.5 were not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting Pack) for this framework version or retarget your application. You can download .NET Framework Developer Packs at https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks  LiteDB  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets    1229

I then attempted to download the .NET Framework 4.5 installer. It no longer exists at the link provided above. I was able to download the 4.5.1 installer, but it wasn't what the solution wanted.

I really don't want to waste more time on this. Can someone please just either point me to where I can get a Zip of the latest compiled build or create one and add a link to it?

Thanks, just really frustrated.

Comment: You already found the litedb.studio github. It has a "releases" section. There you should find the compiled executable.

Comment: And the target version in the csproj says 4.**7**.2 which is still bad, but not as bad as 4.5.2 ...

Comment: Ah yes, Fildor. After I logged into Git, I was able to see Releases. Thanks!

Comment: Is your issue solved by this?

Comment: Additional hint: If you need any 4.x .NET Framework you can use the newest 4.x, actually  4.8.1